Export Redshift data to Microsoft Access
I have my application data directly saved in Amazon Redshift. Now I want to directly import that data in Microsoft Access for internal working. How can I achieve this?
Currently I'm using Excel as a middleman to import my data from Redshift and then again import that csv/xlsx file to Microsoft Access using Coefficient addin.

Install the Redshift ODBC driver. Create an ODBC data source (DSN) for your Redshift database. Import into Access from that data source.
